# Using @observable in Swift, I want to periodically refresh the ObservedObject using a timer. How do I do this?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, observedobject

I am writing an app that pulls data from a website and displays it using SwiftUI.

My main view has an `@ObservedObject` which is of type `DataStore()`, and which is used in the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var store = DataStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(store.zones) { zone in
...
```

The data model is defined as:

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var zones: [SonosZone] = []
        
    init() {
        getZones()
    }
    
    func getZones() {
        Api().getZones { (zones) in
            self.zones = zones
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call `getZones()` every 30 seconds. How do I do this?

I'm guessing that I use code like this somewhere, but I don't know where to put it, or how to call the function in the closure:

```
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { _ in
            getZones()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var zones: [SonosZone] = []
        
    init() {
        getZones()
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.getZones()
        }
    }
    
    
    func getZones() {
        Api().getZones { (zones) in
            self.zones = zones
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the init() you can call getZones() once instead of twice here by saving the reference to the timer, then calling `refreshTimer.fire()` I.E. `let refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(... ) { }   refreshTimer.fire()`